How is EstimatedMaxTimeLag calculated?
I’m trying to understand how the EstimatedMaxTimeLag metric is calculated in Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK).
From what I know, this metric estimates the time (in seconds) a consumer group is behind the latest data in a topic. However, the exact formula or process isn’t entirely clear to me.
Could someone confirm if the following understanding is correct:

Is this metric calculated based on MaxOffsetLag and the average message consumption rate? If so, how is the average consumption rate determined?

